# Wimbledon Tennis Championship 2004, women's single, semi-final (Sharapova vs. Davenport): July 1st or June 30th?

Tags: tennis, match-identification

I find multiple sources having both dates for this match: either **2004-06-30**, or **2004-07-01**. Wikipedia is no help in multiple articles, as single matches aren't broken down to dates.

I fear that from **USA**'s perspective it was June 30th, while on location (**London**) it was already July 1st. But since agencies and article writers are still not paying interest in stating timezones I'm lost on this. Inspecting pictures is no help either, as sometimes "*date created*" means "*date modified*" due to improper metadata usage.

Maybe the match was paused by raining and continued the other day, but I haven't read that anywhere.

---

Additionally I'd also like to know the on-location dates of Sharapova's other matches during Wimbledon 2004, but that's more a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ladies semi-finals at Wimbledon are, unless delayed, played on the second Thursday of the Championship so the match will have been on the 1st July. (The men's semi-finals follow on the Friday, followed by the ladies final on the Saturday). I don't think there are any situations in which the ladies semi-final would be pulled *forwards* to the Wednesday.

This is supported by the [BBC News report of the match](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/tennis/3854907.stm) which is at 15:25 GMT on the 1st July.

Comment: The "**second Thursday**" is an important background knowledge that is stated nowhere - thanks for that! Are there similar rules for all other matches? The article is not that much of a help - it even states "*Last Updated*", which is never bound to its content. The content never mentions the date, or time - it could refer to any given past. When an article was written and/or published rarily helps identifying the actual time the action has happened.